# Check file size before upload on server in IE Asp.net Jquery HttpHandler

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am working on a file upload control using jQuery and HttpHandler to upload file asynchronously in ASP.NET C#. I want to check file size before upload it on server in non-IE browser (e.g Mozilla, chrome) I can easily check the file size but in IE I am not able to check file size on client side.
I have also tried to use ActiveX but it is not working in IE 7 or later version.
Is there any other way to get file size in IE before it upload to server?

Answer (score 0):

there is no cross browser solution to it, what you can do is have an ajax function which calls to your server side function which is easy to do in c sharp using ContentLength and quickly check the size of the file via function and then call your main function this would be ideal and cross browser as per my thinking.

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Hi Abhi, Currently I am doing same as u suggested. I was searching another way to do it if possible. problem occurs only when I am using IE any way thanks for your response